# Having a number of topics/posts column or using COUNT

Tags: sql

I'm looking for the best way to handle this.

Would you make a columns called e.g: `num_posts` and `num_topics` in the forums table and a `num_posts` in topics table or use a query to count the number of topics and posts? Same with having a `num_posts` column in the users table. And for everything else like getting the last poster and date in a specific forum, and topic and so on.

The bad side with this as I can see it is i have to update them whenever a user deletes a post/topic. Like if they delete a post I have to update the last_post column in forum to the post date of the previous post, update the topic, update the user, with making queires i dont have to do that. but how is the performance?

What's considered best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Both works.

There is no *best practise* here, this mostly depends on how the tables are set up and indexed, how your RDBMS reacts and how big is the load on the database.

If indexed properly, querying your tables everytime for getting those numbers of posts or topics shouldn't slow down the overall load process very much. Modern RDBMS will put those queries into their query cache if configured, so this'll speed it up even more.

However, I know that some forum engines (like phpbb) actually have those numbers in the table as you have described. As far as I know they've done it to not to rely too much onto the database (different RDBMS react differently). So its not wrong to do it like this.

My personal preference would be to let the database do the job and avoid coding the overhead functions for updating those fields as long as possible.